# Microk8s air gapped install issues

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

Followed the [instructions](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/installing-microk8s-offline-or-in-an-airgapped-environment/21545/2) for this tutorial in order to install microk8s in an air-gapped environment to no avail.

Upon attempting the "Deploy MicroK8s cluster" step the following command fails: `sudo snap ack microk8s.assert && sudo snap install ./microk8s.snap --classic`. Whereas the install instructions for core20 works just fine.

Upon executing the `... micork8s.snap --classic` install, it declares that it is `- Ensuring that the prerequisites for "microk8s" are available`. Obviously this fails because I am on an air gapped network.

Any Ideas?